# Adding views does not call MEF Import statements

Tags: mvvm, mef

I have a view controlled by a view model (using MEF) that allows a user to selected items from a drop down list.  Each item that the user selects populates a tab control that is defined as a region.  The view model instantiates a view, assigns it a view model, then adds it to the region:

```
ProjectDetailView view = new ProjectDetailView();
ProjectDetailViewModel viewModel = new ProjectDetailViewModel();
viewModel.CurrentProject = project;
view.DataContext = viewModel;
RegionManager.Regions["SelectedItemsRegion"].Add(view);
```

This all works fine from the UI perspective.  The project detail view model, however, has [Import] statements on it to receive an EventAggregator for publishing events.

```
[Import]
public IEventAggregator EventAggregator { get; set; }
```

Because I'm only adding views to a region and not doing a request navigate to a specific URI, the composition never occurs (or at least it doesn't appear to) so EventAggregator is always null.  How do I get these dynamically added views to go through the process of importing the requested classes?  Is there a compose method I can call on a specific view so things get resolved?

Comment: I've recently hit the same problem. I changed my code from RegisterViewWithRegion to .Add, but I've found out that the [Import] are not satisfied. I've also tried to implement the IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification interface, which is never called. Anyone has an update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a factory class to instantiate `EventAggregator`, like so:

```
public EventAggregatorFactory
{
    [Export(typeof(IEventAggregator))]
    public IEventAggregator Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return new EventAggregator();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, move the `Export` declaration into the factory class.  This should allow proper instantiation of the `Import` of EventAggregator when the viewmodel is invoked.